# Scala methods and higher-kinded type parameters

Tags: scala, generics, type-parameter

I am trying to define a method in scala that takes a generic type of `S[_] <: Seq[Double]` and returns a S[FixedLoad] (FixedLoad is a concrete type). But my implementation gives me errors and I can't figure out why. Despite I have tried so many times to understand parametric types and higher-kinded types, my knowledge grows so slow.

What I am trying to achieve is to not lose the concrete type of S (the sequence subtype).

Here is the code:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

class FixedLoad(val id: Int, val positionInT: Int, val amplitude: Double) {
  override def toString: String = s"FixedLoad($id, $positionInT, $amplitude)"
}

object Load {

  implicit def toFixedLoads[S[_] <: Seq[Double]](l: S[Double])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, FixedLoad, S[FixedLoad]]): S[FixedLoad] = {
    l.map(_ => new FixedLoad(1, 1, 1)).to[S]
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(toFixedLoads(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)))
  }

}
```

and the errors:

```
Error:(16, 13) inferred type arguments [List] do not conform to method toFixedLoads's type parameter bounds [S[_] <: Seq[Double]]
    println(toFixedLoads(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)))

Error:(16, 30) type mismatch;
 found   : List[Double]
 required: S[Double]
    println(toFixedLoads(List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Change `toFixedLoads[S[_] <: Seq[Double]]` to `toFixedLoads[S[A] <: Seq[A]]`

**Long answer:**

When you say `S[_]`, that's a *higher kinded type*. Or, in other words, it's a *type constructor*. That means it takes a type to produce the final *proper type*. Here are some examples:

- `List` - takes a type, e.g. `Int`, to produce the proper type `List[Int]`
- `Option` - takes a type, e.g. `Int`, to produce the proper type `Option[Int]`

etc.

Type constructors of this kind are often represented as `* -> *`. You provide one type and you get a type back. There are other kinds as well; for example, `Map` and `Either` need two types to produce the proper type (e.g. `Map[Int, String]` or `Either[Error, Foo]`), so their kind is `* -> * -> *`. Think of it as a curried type constructor; takes a type and returns a function that takes a type and then you get the final, proper type. Or in other words, takes two types to produce the final, proper type. You might also have a type constructor that needs a type constructor to build the proper type (e.g. `Monad[F[_]]`), in which case the kind is `(* -> *) -> *` (for example, `List -> Monad[List]`).

So when you say your method is expecting a parameter of type `S[Double]` and you pass `List(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)`, compiler infers `S` to be `List`, and it complains about `List[A]` not being a subtype of `Seq[Double]` for any `A`. Your first attempt at fixing this might be `F[_] <: Seq[_]`, but that can't compile, because the inner types still don't align. We need to "connect" them with something like `F[A] <: Seq[A] for some A`, which can be written simply as `F[A] <: Seq[A]`.

A good question might be "can I say `S <: Seq[Double]`?" Sure, `S` represents a proper type, so you totally could! Something like this works just fine:

```
def foo[S <: Seq[Double]](s: S) = println(s)
foo(List(1.0, 2.0)) // prints List(1.0, 2.0)
```

But of course, your `S` has a "hole" in it, because your method parameter is of type `S[Double]`, so it's not applicable in your case.

Comment: I strongly suggest not writing `S[Double] <: Seq[Double]`. `Double` doesn't refer to the standard library class when you do that. Rather, `Double` is a local type variable. The bound `S[Double] <: Seq[Double]`, in this context, means "for all types `Double`, then `S[Double] <: Seq[Double]`". Write something clearer, like `S[X] <: Seq[X]`. You can observe this meaning in `class X[+A]; def m[S[Double] <: X[Double]](s: S[Int]): X[Int] = s`. To convert `S[Int]` to `X[Int]`, the quantified bound is instantiated with `Double = Int` to get `S[Int] <: X[Int]`.

Comment: @HTNW Agreed, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I think this answer needs more extensive rewording. For one, "By fixing your S[_] into S[A], you say that you don't really need a type constructor" is blatantly false. The method still needs a type constructor; it's just that there's a bound on it.

Comment: And `Map`/`Either` are very much not curried and their kind shouldn't be represented as `* -> * -> *`.

Comment: @HTNW "A different bound", since there are bounds in both cases too.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov I disagree. If we allow ourselves to see `Map[A, B]` as a function on the type level `(A, B) => Map[A, B]`, than we can equally view it as `A => B => Map[A, B]`. Sure, it's not curried on the syntax level; we can't just provide `A` and obtain a `B => Map[A, B]`, but the principle stays. The only reason I mentioned currying is to justify `* -> * -> *`, which is a common way of representing such HKT.

@HTNW Again agreed, my wording was completely off. Please check if the answer makes more sense now. Answering questions like these helps me improve my own knowledge too.

Comment: @slouc This is the common way to represent the kind (not the higher-kinded type) in Haskell, where they _are_ curried, in Scala I can see no reason to use it instead of `(*, *) -> *`. On the other hand, after checking, this notation _is_ the one used in the original https://adriaanm.github.io/files/higher.pdf paper, and in the output of `:kind`. So I still don't like it, but it does seem to be the standard one.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov Yeah, I agree it's misleading in Scala, but I assumed it's adopted from general notation. It's good advice to keep this in mind, thanks.

Comment: @slouc "compiler infers `S[_]` to be `List`, and it complains about `List` not being a subtype of `Seq[Double]`" I'd rather say it infers `S` to be `List` and complains about `List[A]` not being a subtype of `Seq[Double]` _for all `A`_, which is what the bound requires. An example of a higher-kinded type satisfying the bound would be `type LD[A] = List[Double]`. "`F[A] <: Seq[A] for some A`" should be "for all `A`".