# Scala .zip with higher-kinded types, weird behaviour

Tags: scala, collections, higher-kinded-types

Following the question and answer in [Scala methods and higher-kinded type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56240426/scala-methods-and-higher-kinded-type-parameters) where I asked how to create a method with higher-kinded parameters so I could use any Seq, I am facing now a weird problem when using the .zip method. The code below doesn't compile, the complire reports:

```
Error:(18, 28) type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[X]
 required: S[X]
        itrA.zip(itrB).map {
```

I don't know where S[X] is transformed to Seq[X]. However, if I replace the code with the call to .zip with a more simple one (the commented one) which simply sums both heads of itrA and itrB and returns ItrA, the compilation is successful.

The code is:

```
object SeqOps {

  def sum[X: Numeric, S[Y] <: Seq[Y]](s: Seq[S[X]])
    (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, X, S[X]]): Seq[X] =

  /*
      This code compiles
       s.reduce{(itrA, itrB) =>
          val num = implicitly[Numeric[X]]
          val sum = new num.Ops(itrA.head).+(itrB.head)
          itrA
          */

      s.reduce{(itrA, itrB) =>
        itrA.zip(itrB).map { // it seems that itrB loses the type here :/
          case (a, b) =>
            val num = implicitly[Numeric[X]]
            val sum = new num.Ops(a).+(b)
            sum
      }

  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    sum(Seq(Vector(1), Vector(1)))
  }

}
```

The questions are: Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't know that if you `zip` two `S[X]` that it can somehow build an `S[(X, X)]` out of it. For this to work, you need a `CBF` that knows how to build an `S[(X, X)]`.

Unfortunately, there don't seem to be any implicits that would be able to build e.g. `Vector[Int]` out of a generic `Seq[_]`, so you need more information about the type of the collection from which you're building. The idea is that traits with `-Like` name can provide this information. In this case, `SeqLike[X, Repr]` carries the `Repr`-type around.

If you now stare long enough at the [signature of `zip` in `SeqLike`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SeqLike.html#zip[B](that:scala.collection.GenIterable[B]):Seq[(A,B)]):

```
def zip
  [A1 >: A, B, That]
  (that: GenIterable[B])
  (implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, (A1, B), That])
: That
```

then you'll see that you can give it a `CBF` that has `Repr` in the first component. So you might try something like this (note `with SeqLike` and two `CBF`s - one for `zip`, another one for `map`):

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.language.higherKinds
import scala.collection.SeqLike

object SeqOps {


  def sum[X: Numeric, S[Y] <: Seq[Y] with SeqLike[Y, S[Y]]]
    (s: Seq[S[X]])
    (implicit 
      cbf1: CanBuildFrom[S[_], X, S[X]],
      cbf2: CanBuildFrom[S[_], (X, X), S[(X, X)]]
    )
  : Seq[X] = {
    val num = implicitly[Numeric[X]]
    import num._
    s.reduce(_.zip(_)(cbf2).map{ case (a, b) => a + b })
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(sum(Seq(Vector(1), Vector(1))))     // Vector(2)
    println(sum(Seq(List(2, 3), List(4, 5))))   // List(6, 8)
  }

}
```

Another remark: In certain cases, it is easier to think of `Nothing` as of `Unobtanium`. If your `CBF` requires `Unobtanium` to build an `S[X]`, it's probably not good for anything, because where do you want to get `Unobtanium`?